# Android :: Need Galaxy note3,4,5,6 AVD

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I want to test my mobile application on galaxy note3,4,5,6.

Please tell me the configuration for the same or tell me the specification for these to create AVD .as these are not available in genymotion.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but in case you still need it or someone else finds this post looking for it, here is the link to Samsungs official Emulator Skin for most of their phones and tablets.

http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000095

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to use the Note 3 specs in an Android emulator. Full HD and 3GB RAM is something that the Emulator and possibly your machine can't handle.
So use full HD emulators instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378446/samsung-galaxy-note-iii-emulator-settings for note 3
And full HD Emulator will use large amount of resources and takes longer time to load
One more thing And I don't know about note 5 and 6. I assume they are S5 and S6.

Comment: you can refer this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252598/creating-galaxy-s5-emulator